# labyrinth solver on python language

Tags: python

just a small labyrinth solver. try it to on python but dont even understand why it doesnt print anything. Im just started with python and trying to actually translate my teachers code from cpp just for interest.
need to reach to the destination after visiting each cell

```
m = [
    [2,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0]
]

STOP = 34
r = 0
c = 0


def init( r_: int = 0, c_: int = 0) -> None:
    r = 0
    c = 0

def step(r,c,level):
    if level==STOP-1:
        if r == 3 and c == 5:
            for i in range(0,level):
                print("("+init(int(r),int(c))+"," + init(int(r),int(c)) + ") - ")
            print("(3,5)\n")
            return True
    else:
        return False
    m[r][c]=1

    if c > 0 and  m[r][c - 1] == 0:
        if step(r, c - 1, level + 1):
            return True

    if c < 5 and m[r][c + 1] == 0:
        if (step(r, c + 1, level + 1)):
            return True


    if r > 0 and m[r - 1][c] == 0:
        if (step(r - 1, c, level + 1)):
            return True

    if r < 5 and m[r + 1][c] == 0:
        if (step(r + 1, c, level + 1)):
            return True

    m[r][c] = 0
    return False
def main(argc, argv):
    step(0, 1, 0)
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I suggest you to learn the language fundamentals first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S, F, W, X = 1, 2, 0, None
FIELD = [[X,S,W,W,W,W],
         [W,W,W,W,W,W],
         [W,W,W,W,W,W],
         [W,W,W,W,W,F],
         [W,W,W,X,W,W],
         [W,W,W,W,W,W]]
ROWS = len(FIELD)
COLS = len(FIELD[0])

START_POS  = [(i, line.index(S)) for i, line in enumerate(FIELD) if S in line][0]
FINISH_POS = [(i, line.index(F)) for i, line in enumerate(FIELD) if F in line][0]
STEPS      = sum(line.count(W) for line in FIELD) + 1

print("Start:", START_POS, "\nFinish:", FINISH_POS, "\nTotal steps:", STEPS)

def do_step(level, path, points):
    global FIELD
    r, c = points[-1]   
    if r<0 or c<0 or r>=ROWS or c>=COLS or FIELD[r][c] == X:
        return
    if level == STEPS and (r, c) == FINISH_POS:
        print("Found path:", path) 
        yy, xx = zip(*points)
        plt.plot(xx, yy, "-ok")
        plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
        plt.show()
        exit()

    current = FIELD[r][c] 
    FIELD[r][c] = X      
    for dr, dc, dir in ((-1,0,'^'), (0,1,'>'), (1,0,'v'), (0,-1,'<')):
        do_step(level+1, path+dir, points+[(r+dr,c+dc)])
    FIELD[r][c] = current 
do_step(0, "", [START_POS])
print("No path's found.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't automatically call main like c does, nor does it require a main function. Your code can just live in the top level (e.g. `print('hello world')` is a valid, complete program)

Change this line:

```
def main(argc, argv):
```

to this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: anyway im stuck i think somewhere in step func